# Odd Constructor

Tags: c#

What does ~  do. This is an Asp.Net v2 class I have just inherited. Class works OK
Theres a default constructor
under it is ~VNC  What is ~ used for ?

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace UtopianClasses
{
    public class VNC
    {
        public VNC(){ }

        ~VNC() {
             GC.Collect();
        }

        public String VNCViewFilesLocationMCR
        {
            get {
              return  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VNCViewFilesLocation"].ToString();    
            }
```

... Rest of Class

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, it's a destructor. However, not only should you probably not be explicitly implementing a destructor, you **really** should not be forcing a GC collection from inside a destructor, because the destructor is invoked by the garbage collector itself. As near as I can tell, that's a code smell in any GCed language.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx), not a constructor.  They are typically used to release native resources or handles in classes that wrap native APIs.

That being said, adding a constructor that calls `GC.Collect()` is a bad idea.  The destructor is only called during finalization, so the garbage collector is already cleaning up this object, and any object this object referenced.  There is no reason to do this, as it just adds overhead, and will actually slow down the system.

This was probably written by somebody with a C++ background who did not understand the intricacies of memory management in .NET.  I would recommend removing this altogether.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but then I'd imagine a decent C++ programmer (I'm not one!) would only be cleaning up things the object was responsible for.

Answer (score 0):

They're actually called Finalizers in .net. They're called when the GC cleans up that object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(VS.71).aspx

Comment: The C# language spec calls them destructors (unfortunately).